# How to partially change the default stylesheet for the current Notebook

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Is there a way to make a minor modification of the **default appearance** of cells in the current Notebook without specifying the all set of options? 
For example, I wish to have all `Cell`s with style "Text" in the current Notebook by default having

```
 CellMargins -> {{Inherited, Inherited}, {0, Inherited}}
```

All the other options should be inherited from the default stylesheet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you should use Format menu and choose Edit Stylesheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up Edit stylesheet from Format menu.

Then paste there the following:

```
Cell[StyleData["Text"], 
 CellMargins -> {{Inherited, Inherited}, {0, Inherited}}]
```

**EDIT**: Adding a screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: Could you include a screen capture, please?

Comment: After doing what you suggest all text cells in the Notebook looks as if would have `CellMargins->0`. It seems that `Inherited` does not work. Is it possible to make it working?

Comment: I would like to change only bottom cell margin but leave all others as they are in the default stylesheet whatever it is.

Comment: @Alexey Yes, it appears that Inherited is not supported, i.e. interpreted as zero. In case it helps, the Default stylesheet specifies {{66,10},{7,7}} for cell margins. You can set margins explicitly.

Comment: Stylesheets could be changed from one *Mathematica* version to another. In *Mathematica* 5.2 and 7.0.1 by default `CellMargins->{{60, 10}, {7, 7}}`. At the same time, a user can specify his own stylesheet. It would be nice to have working inheritance and don't worry about incompatibilities...